# O365 Annoying Popups

Tags: office-365

I am not sure if this forum is for O365, if not please guide me to the right forum.

I have an O365 tenant and once I login and on authentication I am getting these annoying Popups every minute and even if I click on Yes or No these popoups don't go away.Please advise what needs to be done.These popups keeps coming everytime I am moving between apps within the waffle menu.

I have attached the screenshots of the popups.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like you are using IE less than version 11 with `Websites in less privileged web content zone can navigate into this zone.` disbaled in “Trusted Sites“ zone

**To overcome this issue follow the mentioned steps below:**

- Open internet explorer > Tools > Internet Options.
- Select the “Security” Tab.
- Choose “Trusted Sites“.
- Select “Custom Level…”
- Scroll down to where it says “Websites in less privileged web content zone can navigate into this zone.” Check “Enable“.

[image]

For more details check IE: [Disable ‘The current web page is trying to open a site in your Trusted sites list. Do you want to allow this?’](https://www.technipages.com/ie-disable-current-web-page-is-trying)

Comment: looke like the setting I was looking at is a protection against phishing and social engineering attacks on untrusted sites. It would not be prudent to disable this across the board(whole company) The proper approach is to include all of the Microsoft URLS in the trusted sites list to eliminate the pop ups from occurring when legitimate navigation is occurring. This might work for an individual but not the whole company.Do you agree?